# Memory problem while working with trees in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

In my tree, I have the Node class, which contains the following vector to point to its child nodes:

```
std::vector<Node*> child;
```

the destructor of the class first deletes all the allocated variables, and then deletes the subtrees:

```
~Node() {
    //Deletes all the allocated variables
                     .
                     .
                     .

    //Deletes the subtrees
    for(int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {
        delete child[i];
    }
}
```

There's a method in the Node class to build a tree of a given depth:

```
void createTree(int depth) {
    if(depth == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfChildNodes; i++) {
        child.push_back(new Node());
        child[i]->createTree(depth - 1);
    }
}
```

There's another method that first creates a tree of depth 3, then deletes it and creates another one of depth 4, then 5, until a memory limit is reached:

```
void createMaximumTree() {
    int i, depth = 3;
    struct sysinfo memInfo;
    while(true) {
        createTree(depth);
        sysinfo (&memInfo);
        //Checking if the free memory available to the OS is lower than the limit
        if(memInfo.freeram < limit) {
            std::cout << "Maximum depth: " << depth;
            break;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {
            delete child[i];
        }
        child.clear();
        depth++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {
        delete child[i];
    }
    child.clear();
}
```

If I check the memory usage of this process, I see that even after I delete a tree in the method above, the OS doesn't get its memory back. That's expected, because the process doesn't immediately free the memory after the delete operation, since it might still use it again.

The problem is, if I call the method createMaximumTree() twice, it doesn't return the memory to the OS after I delete the first tree, and instead of using this allocated memory for the second tree, it allocates more memory, causing my computer to run out of RAM. The computer got so slow to the point where I couldn't even switch tabs. This is how I checked the memory.

```
struct sysinfo memInfo;
sysinfo (&memInfo);
std::cout << memInfo.freeram;
createMaximumTree();
sysinfo (&memInfo);
std::cout << memInfo.freeram;
createMaximumTree();
sysinfo (&memInfo);
std::cout << memInfo.freeram;
```

Is this a bug in the memory manager? What can I do to fix this?

(I'm using Debian)

Comment: *Is this a bug in the memory manager? What can I do to fix this?* -- If the compiler's memory manager had such a bug, thousands of programmers would have reported it.  So no, it is more than likely a bug in your code.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfChildNodes; i++) {child.push_back(new Node());child[i]->createTree(depth - 1);` -- Is the intent of this code to call `createTree` on the last node added to the child?  If so, then this loop may not portray this, as using `i` as an index doesn't guarantee this.  It could simply be `child.push_back(new Node());child.back()->createTree(depth - 1);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It works because the vector was empty before the for loop. So the first iteration creates the first child node, and then it calls the function recursively for this child node. Then to the second child node, and so on.

Comment: You're still describing your code.  You need to post a [mcve].  Descriptions of code many times do not tell the real truth.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm trying to make the a minimal example, but it's still going to be very large to post here. It has a lot of methods that call each other. I think the best I can do is around a thousand lines of code.

Comment: "delete[i]" makes no sense, it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: *I think the best I can do is around a thousand lines of code* -- Well that makes it more of a reason why it is your code causing the issue, and that is the size of your code with all of this dynamic memory allocation and raw pointer handling going on.

Comment: @Dragan That was a typo. I fixed it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's the code of a chess engine, so it has to be large and it needs to have memory allocation and pointer handling. There's no escape from that sadly.

Comment: Well, you have a buggy chess game, and you will just need to accept that is what you are dealing with.

Comment: This is the third instance of that question

Comment: There is a lot of escape from it. My advice is to learn to use std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique. Code should rarely contain "new" and "delete". You create a node, you own that node. You pass that node as a child to another node, now the parent owns it. Memory management is actually very easy, as it should be...